# Office365 DNS API

Tags: dns, office365, office365api

Microsoft provides DNS for office365 ([documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-edit-custom-dns-records-in-office-365-af00a516-dd39-4eda-af3e-1eaf686c8dc9)). Right now I'm failing to find out if they provide an API for it.

Comment: I also asked this question in the microsoft forum. Will post an reply as soon as I get an answer: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_domains-mso_o365b/office365-dns-api/94e41af2-e1de-44fe-a626-dc50e2e6fc6a?tm=1525421253904

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no DNS API in the [Office365 API catalog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog).

Source: [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_domains-mso_o365b/office365-dns-api/94e41af2-e1de-44fe-a626-dc50e2e6fc6a?tm=1525421253904)